# what does "allow something to be explored" mean?

Tags: meaning, passive-voice

I am leaning this [post](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.51.2193&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> The factors which consistently affect accuracy are those which
>   directly or indirectly (as in the handling of continuous attributes)
>   allow a greater number and variety of potential trees to be explored.

I assume this part of Abstract could be simplified as "The factors allow trees to be explored".

Don't be bothered by the term "trees", which is a computer scientific notion. You can view it as a robot that can distinguish an image a cat or a dog.

the question is, what does "allow something to be explored" mean?

Answer (score 1):

## It’s a passive voice problem.

In this sentence:

> The factors which consistently affect accuracy are those which directly or indirectly (as in the handling of continuous attributes) allow a greater number and variety of potential trees to be explored.

The trick is to simplify it down to parts.

It seems that the following are **implied**:

> *We are building a method. 
>   We want the method to produce accurate results.*
>   *We will discuss which factors improve accuracy and which don’t.*

So let’s simplify:

> The factors which <s>consistently</s> affect accuracy are those which <s>directly or indirectly (as in the handling of continuous attributes)</s> allow a <s>greater</s> number of <s>potential</s> trees to be explored.

We have:

> The factors which affect accuracy are those which allow a number of trees to be explored.

- Notice that “of potential trees” is a prepositional phrase. You can often remove prepositional phrases from sentences without affecting their grammar. In this case, **of** is modifying “a number”.
- “To be explored” is related to the verb **allow**.

It’s tempting to simplify by getting rid of “a number“, and keep “trees“. For the purposes of the grammar, though, “trees” is in a **prepositional phrase**.  Prepositional phrases are almost always self-contained and can be removed from the sentence without disturbing the grammar.

So, simplify again:

We have:

> The factors which affect accuracy are those which allow a number (of trees) to be explored.

The key is:

- allow (a number) (to be explored)

This is passive voice, which usually **drops of the subject of verbs**.

The subject is implied:

- allow (a number) (to be explored) (**by the method**)

Or:

- allow the method to explore a number.

So a final simplification:

> ** The good factors allow the method to do more, and go faster.**.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this particular case, they're actually very literally saying what their algorithms do.

I read that to mean "we get more accurate results when the software can search more trees", but machine learning isn't my specialty so that's a best guess (without having read the entire paper).